# [AOSP][Android-8.0]surface.aidl moved from frameworks/base to frameworks/native

Tags: android, android-source, aidl

In AOSP (8.0) source I have found `Surface.aidl` moved from `frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/Surface.aidl` to `frameworks/native/aidl/gui/android/view/Surface.aidl`.

Actually the problem is that my application AIDL needs to use Surface class.

Below is the code snippet

```
import android.view.Surface;

interface sampleService {
    void setSurface(in Surface sampleSurface);
}
```

During build my application AIDL not able to resolve the Surface class. But if I add `Surface.aidl` class inside `frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/` then my AIDL compiled successfully and running without error.

Now my question is that `frameworks/base/Android.mk` includes   `frameworks/native/aidl/gui/android/view/Surface.aidl` but still my AIDL not able to import Surface class.

I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help me to find a way out.

Here is the [Change Log](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/8861291)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding inside Android.mk and its working

```
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES += \
        frameworks/native/aidl/gui
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create dummy Surface.aidl file inside your application package with the path like below.

```
src/main/aidl/android/view/Surface.aidl
```

Inside the Surface.aidl put the below code. Since parcelabel class for Surface is available in frameworks/base/core/java/android/view.

```
package android.view;

parcelable Surface;
```

In your sampleService interface import the Surface like below.

```
   import android.view.Surface;
```